# Notation Confusion: Norm 2 or something else?

Tags: notation, vectors, normed-spaces

[image]

Hello! Thanks for taking the time to look at this post. I was wondering if this is notation norm 2. I normally see norm 2 with a subscript but the 2 is superscript here. Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to be sure without any context, but  almost surely the superscript is intended as an exponent, so this is the square of the norm.

Answer (score 1):

Using norm $2$ in this context should be denoted by $\|Ax-b\|_2$. Therefore, my guess is that $\|Ax-b\|^2$ is the square of a norm, for some arbitrary norm.